# Cubic spline that interpolates $f$

Tags: numerical-methods

Given the following cubic spline that interpolates $f$:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
(x+3)^3-9(x+3)^2+22(x+3)-10 & ,-3 \leq x < -1\\  
(x+1)^3-3(x+1)^2-2(x+1)+6 & , -1\leq x <0\\ 
ax^3+bx^2+cx+d & ,0\leq x <2\\ 
(x-2)^3+6(x-2)^2+7(x-2) & ,2 \leq x \leq 3
\end{matrix}\right.$$

It's also given that: $f(-3)=-10, f(-1)=?, f(0)=?, f(2)=0, f(3)=14$.
Which is the value of $c$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Use the fact that $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ must be continuous at $x=0$ and $x=2$

Comment: Ok..So is it $c=-5$?

Comment: I assume so. I haven't done the calculations myself but It looks like a plausible result :)